# array of objects and adding a function as a property and access other properties using this in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an array of objects. I'm trying to not repeat my functions on every object.

First, is the way I implemented my array of interface correct?

Second, how do I properly implement my function on each object? Was not sure if I have to do a call or bind when I assign that function on each object. Or I am completely doing it wrong.

```
//interfaces
export interface IEmployee{
  id: number;
  name: string;
  hourly: number;
  hours_this_week: number;
  paycheck: (() => number);
}

// my function

const calculatePayThisWeek = (): number => {
    return this.hourly * this.hours_this_week;
}

export getEmployees = (): IEmployee[] => {
  return [
     { 
        id: 1,
        name: 'John Doe',
        hourly: 10,
        hours_this_week: 5,
        paycheck: calculatePayThisWeek
     },
     { 
        id: 2,
        name: 'Jane Doe',
        hourly: 15,
        hours_this_week: 8,
        paycheck: calculatePayThisWeek
     }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need `calculatePayThisWeek` to be a `function`, not an arrow function. Arrow functions capture the enclosing `this`, which is not what you want.

You don't need to bind anything. You should annotate `this` in `calculatePayThisWeek` though.

Full solution:

```
interface IEmployee {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  hourly: number;
  hours_this_week: number;
  paycheck: (() => number);
}

// my function
function calculatePayThisWeek(this: IEmployee): number {
    return this.hourly * this.hours_this_week;
}

const getEmployees = (): IEmployee[] => {
  return [
     { 
        id: 1,
        name: 'John Doe',
        hourly: 10,
        hours_this_week: 5,
        paycheck: calculatePayThisWeek
     },
     { 
        id: 2,
        name: 'Jane Doe',
        hourly: 15,
        hours_this_week: 8,
        paycheck: calculatePayThisWeek
     }
  ]
}
```

Comment: i see! that worked thank you. btw, is annotating "this" always expected for typescript?

Comment: It's best practice to annotate `this` in situations like this. You have a free function, but it's meant to be called with a specific `this` — not just with the default `this` of `window`. Whenever that happens, you must annotate `this` in order to be able to use `this` inside the function body without type errors.